# MATLAB: print pdf in black/white

Tags: matlab, pdf-generation

Matlab prints figures in either black/white or color. A black/white print of a figure is NOT the same as a color print tweaked to black/white: *every* color including the light ones is translated as black. (Light colors that look good on screen or a color printer look horrible on a black/white printer)

I would like to print a PDF file of a figure. My problem is that there doesn't seem to be a PDF driver for MATLAB that outputs black/white rather than color.

See the [print](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/print.html) command: `-dpdf` is the PDF driver but it is color.

Is there any way I can do this?

(edit: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f3-84337.html#f3-99776 shows the interactive way of doing this, but I need a programmatic method, otherwise it will get tedious rather quickly.)

Answer (score 4):

You can fully automate the print process: http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/customizing-print-setup/

Comment: Hmm. This doesn't seem to affect `print(fignum, '-dpdf', filename)` even if DriverColor is set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert it to an EPS (`-deps` or `-deps2`) and then use [`eps2pdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5782-eps2pdf) (which uses [GhostScript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/)) to convert that into a PDF. I generally convert all my figures to this way.